# Using grep to read a paragraph on Solaris

Tags: grep

How can I grep a paragraph from a file in the Solaris operating system? I tried the `-p` option used in AIX, but it's not useful in Solaris.

`grep -p Accept` is not working in Solaris. Is there any other option?

Comment: For future reference, I probably would have asked this on [Super User](http://www.superuser.com). Don't go and ask it there now though. If others agree with me, it will be migrated there automagically :)

Comment: I didn't understand:-(

Comment: That's ok! You're not the first, and you certainly won't be the last! Besides, someone with over 100k rep thought your question was relevant to answer, and there haven't been enough people voting with me to move your question to superuser, so maybe I was wrong anyway. Shell commands/scripting is a bit of a grey area.

Comment: Have you checked `/opt/swf/bin` for a GNU grep? It is probably not in the PATH.

Answer (score 2):

Awk is present on every unix (it's [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html)). Anything that grep or sed can do, can be coded in awk (but it's not always straightforward).

Awk operates record by record. The default record separator is a newline (i.e. by default, a record is a line), but if the [`RS` variable](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html#tag_04_06_13_03) is set to an empty value, then the record separator is one or more empty lines (i.e. a record is a paragraph).

```
awk -v RS= '/needle/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the standard `grep`, there isn't a sensible alternative.  You can either install a more capable version of `grep` (perhaps GNU `grep`), or you can use Perl (or perhaps Python) to emulate `grep`.